# vuex unknown action type: login WIT problem

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I have faced a problem in `login.vue` there nothing to be a problem but the message is in title and showing with red notation in file

**login.vue**

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'
import {LockClosedIcon} from '@heroicons/vue/solid'
import GuestLayout from "../components/GuestLayout.vue";
import store from "../store";
import router from "../router";

let loading = ref(false);
let errorMsg = ref("");

const user = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    remember: false
}

function login() {

    console.log(user)

    loading.value = true;
    store.dispatch('login', user)
        .then(() => {
            loading.value = false;
            router.push({name: 'app.dashboard'})
        })
        .catch(({response}) => {
            loading.value = false;
            errorMsg.value = response.data.message;
        })
}

</script>
```

facing with the following problem

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')

```
at login (Login.vue:118:9)

at runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:1481:16

at callWithErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:155:22)

at callWithAsyncErrorHandling (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:164:21)

at HTMLFormElement.invoker (runtime-dom.esm-bundler.js:369:13)
```

the **then** word is in login function.

Comment: It's very specific to your store implementation. If it's Vuex then there's no place for such error, an action always returns an error. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem.

Comment: It would be nice to see the store code but I'm going to go ahead and guess that the action `login` does not return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) which would cause the `.then()` statement to fail with an undefined error.

Comment: Yes it is, now I faced with undefined error, here what is the problem. I didn't get anything form this error.